# Google shortcuts key to select first research result link?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, google-search

I would like to know if there is a shortcut key to select the first result research from Google ?

Thank you all in advance !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not trying to solve a programming problem

Comment: ok sorry next time I will pay attention to it ;)

Comment: This may be the 10 millionth question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are searching for the "tab"-key?

Comment: thank you webprogrammer! it was what I was searching for ;)

Answer (score 3):

"If you add http://www.google.com/search?q=%s&btnI=Im+Feeling+Lucky as a custom search engine you can also specify a keyword to associate it with (this is done in the same window). So for example, if you associate it with ">" you can just type "> gmail" in the address bar and pressing Enter will take you directly to www.gmail.com"

from:

"https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Y1So8rpT-Og"

If you are typing and autofinish starts then you can move your cursor to the end of one of the suggestions and click I'm Feeling Lucky.

Also if you just click I'm Feeling Lucky on your google home page then it takes you to all the doodles.

Hope this helps.